GitHub Pages with Vite and React: Absolute Path Issue for JavaScript Rendering
I am deploying a React project using Vite to GitHub Pages. My GitHub Pages URL is:
https://adelelawady.github.io/
I have a project called cv_wizardy, so the project should be accessible at:
https://adelelawady.github.io/cv_wizardy/
However, when I deploy and upload the project files, the root JavaScript only renders when the path is set to the absolute path /. It does not work correctly when accessed via the relative path https://adelelawady.github.io/cv_wizardy/.
Setup:
I'm using Vite with React.
The issue occurs with the JavaScript files that seem to be looking for the root directory (/) instead of the /cv_wizardy/ subpath.
I've also checked that the repository is correctly configured to use GitHub Pages.
What am I missing or doing wrong here? How can I make the project work with the correct relative paths?
I've ensured the base property in vite.config.ts is set to /cv_wizardy/:
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
  base: '/cv_wizardy/',
  plugins: [
    react(),
    mode === "development" && componentTagger(),
  ].filter(Boolean),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
}));

